# Sum arrays element by element in JSonata

Tags: arrays, sum, jsonata

I need to sum 2 arrays element by element, considering also potential "null" in the data.

Here a body example:

```
{
  "response": {
    "doc": [
      {
        "channels": {
          "channel1": {
            "samples": [
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4,
              5
            ]
          },
          "channel2": {
            "samples": [
              null,
              null,
              3,
              4,
              null
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I need to obtain is an array as follows:

[null,null,6,8,null]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum the two arrays element by element using JSONata with the following expression:

```
response.doc.{
    "result": $zip(channels.channel1.samples, channels.channel2.samples) ~> 
    $map(function($v, $i, $a) {
        $v[0] != null and $v[1] != null ? $v[0] + $v[1] : null
    })
}
```

Feel free to play with this expression on [Stedi JSONata Playground](https://stedi.link/fhYqwnE)

Comment: $zip-based approach would only work if you know how many channels there would be in the `channels` object

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(
  response.doc.channels.* ~> $reduce(function($result, $channel, $jindex) {
    $map($channel.samples, function($sample, $index) {(
      $currentSum := $result[$index];
      $currentSum = null or $sample = null 
        ? null 
        : $not($exists($currentSum)) 
          ? $sample 
          : $currentSum + $sample
    )})
  }, [])
)
```

The idea is to loop over all the channels, map over samples of each channel and sum them up with the accumulated result.

Check it out on the live playground: https://stedi.link/67ffqtm